# How to install Ubuntu in a toshiba a A-45 satellite laptop?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have tried several time to install Ubuntu in my Toshiba laptop model A45.

I have not been able to do it, my Toshiba laptop does not recognize the Ubuntu CD to boot from it and it will not boot from my USB stick. I only be able to installed Ubuntu with Windows help but it does not work same way has in my other comp.

Does any one has any idea of what can I do to properly install Ubuntu in my satellite Toshiba A45?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have burned the Ubuntu disc at the slowest speed possible, this reduces disc failure.

Once you have done that, insert the disc and restart the laptop, look for the option to edit the boot options and selecting to boot from the CD/DVD.

Make sure that you save the boot options, once the PC restarts then the disc should be identified.

If you are successful installing Ubuntu that way, then make sure you alter the boot menu again so it goes from CD/DVD back to the hard drive.